# Trying to write data to a database using ASP.NET - error "Must declare the scalar variable" and unsure why

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm a novice user and this is my first time using this system. Just trying to do a very simple function just now involving entering data into forms, pressing a submit button and then storing the values in my database. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I am getting the error

> Must declare the scalar variable @forename

```
@{


// Initialize variables
var forename = "";
var surname = "";
var email = "";
var street = "";
var gender = "";
var towncity = "";
var postcode = "";
var cardno = "";
var expiry = "";
var securecode = "";
var password = "";

// If this is a POST request validate and process data
if (IsPost) {
    forename = Request.Form["forename"];
    surname = Request.Form["surname"];
    gender = Request.Form["gender"];
    street = Request.Form["street"];
    towncity = Request.Form["townCity"];
    postcode = Request.Form["postcode"];
    cardno = Request.Form["cardno"];
    expiry = Request.Form["expiry"];
    securecode = Request.Form["securecode"];
    password = Request.Form["password"];
    email = Request.Form["email"];

    var db = Database.Open("calcinema");
    var cmd = "INSERT INTO Account (Forename, Surname, Email, Street, Gender, TownCity, Postcode, Cardnumber, Expiry, SecureCode, Password) VALUES (@forename, @surname, @email, @street, @gender, @towncity, @postcode, @cardno, @expiry, @securecode, @password)";
    db.Execute(cmd, forename, surname, email, street, gender, towncity, postcode, cardno, expiry, securecode, password);
    Response.Redirect("~/Browse");

    }
}
```

It's most likely something really simple but I can't see it and I've followed templates/tutorials that follow the same structure as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

`Webmatrix.Database` maps parameters in query by index, not by name. So instead of using `@forename` you should use `@0`, and so on:

```
var cmd = "INSERT INTO Account (Forename, Surname, Email, Street, Gender, TownCity, Postcode, Cardnumber, Expiry, SecureCode, Password) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, ...)";
```

Other parts of code should not change. Not a good approach maybe, but WebMatrix gives no other options.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's fixed that problem but now I get the error

"String or binary data would be truncated"

it points to the db.Execute statement

Comment: @user3511289, that means one of the input values exceeds the table constraints. For example you might have `nvarchar(10)` and value is 20 characters long, or similar

Comment: got it! for some idiotic reason I accidentally had the password as nvarchar(1). It works now, thank you for your help

Comment: @Andrei 'Not a good approach maybe', but it means that you can use the Database Helper with OleDb and ODBC data sources that don't support named parameters.

Comment: @MikeBrind, thank you, very good case of where this might be useful! That is exactly the reason I said "maybe".